# using a boolean method to return true if the string inputed is alphabetically arranged

Tags: java

I'm writing a program that takes a string and returns a boolean indicating whether the word is alphabetically arranged e.g. abdest,  acknow, adempt etc.

My problem is that the program returns no output but just terminates... Please I would really appreciate some corrections.
Here is my code:

```
public class test{ 
    public static boolean Abecedarian(String s) {
        String alp="";
        for(char c ='A'; c<='Z'; c++){ 
            alp +=c; 
        }           
        if(s.equals(alp)){ 
            return true; 
        }else 
            return false; 
        } 
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        Abecedarian("victor"); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: One, you're missing a bracket `{` after `else`. Second, you're not doing anything with the boolean that's returned so of course nothing visual is going to happen. Hint: Use an if-statement with the method call to do something such as printing some output. Also, the program logic will not do what you suggested (checking if a string's character are in alphabetic order)

Comment: `the program returns no output but just terminates` Your code does not doing anything to let the user know of a result. Perhaps you wish to print it to the command line `System.out.println(Abecedarian("victor"));`

Comment: @copeg  oww right....gush i did'nt even see that...thanks but the program is returning false when i invoke it with "abcd"....do you know why?

Comment: `do you know why?` Yes...but for now I'd recommend adding some debug `println` statements in there to check what the values are and help you debug  (hints: case,  `alp` value is the entire alphabet)

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String [] words = {"abdest", "acknow", "adempt" };
    for (String word : words) {
        System.out.println(" isAbecedarian '"+word+"': "+isAbecedarian(word));
    }
}

public static boolean isAbecedarian(String s) {
    if (s == null ) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error");
    if (s.length() < 2) return true;
    char last = s.charAt(0);
    char current;
    for (int i = 1; i < s.length(); i++) {
        current = s.charAt(i);
        if (current < last) {
            return false;
        }
        last = current;
    }
    return true;
}
```

output:

```
isAbecedarian 'abdest': true
isAbecedarian 'acknow': true
isAbecedarian 'adempt': true
```

Comment: What should the result be for the string "Abdest" ?

Comment: @FredK `isAbecedarian("Abdest")` returns `true`

Comment: thanks alot @DavidPérezCabrera , but i'm a little bit new to java do mind please explaining a little bit because i'm getting kinda confused with the flow of execution at method isAbecedarian...what does "throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error");" do?  and why are two instances returning true ? please:)

Comment: @DavidPérezCabrera , please never mind explaining , i now understand that the comparing of char values is making use of their ASCII numbers.....this is a very smart one thanks very much again